# mysqli_fetch_rows result in html

Tags: php

How to foreach mysqli_fetch_rows result in html? I am getting errors all the time.. I also tried different things...

```
   $pqr = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($pqr))
      {

<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="'.$row[2].''.$row[3].'">
                                      <img src="'.$row[2].''.$row[3].' " width="270"/></a>



      }
```

**Error msg:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.$row[2].''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: I have provided with the solution. Have a try and let me know if you face any hindrance in development.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `{}` to concatenate the variable and normal string.

Like this,

```
echo "<img src='{$row[2]}{$row[3]}' width='270'/></a>
     <a class='fancybox' rel='gallery1' href='{$row[2]}{$row[3]}'>";
```

If you're using double quote for `echo` make sure you use single quote in HTML content to avoid Syntax and Parse Errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow code

```
    $html="";
    $pqr = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($pqr))
      {
        $html .= "<a class='fancybox' rel='gallery1' href='".$row[2].$row[3]."' width='270'>";
        $html .= "<img src='".$row[2].$row[3]."' width='270'>";
        $html .= "</a>";

      }
      echo $html;

      }
      echo $html;
```

Comment: Thanks but error is still here: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'fancybox' (T_STRING) in

Comment: Try once again above code.

Comment: I removed last } and echo and works like a charm.. Thank you!!!

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are printing data in HTML

```
<?php
$pqr = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($pqr)) {
?> <!--close php tags-->
     <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="<?php echo $row[2] . $row[3] ?>">
     <img src="<?php echo $row[2] . $row[3] ?>" width="270"/></a>

<?php } ?> <!--loop end-->
```

NOTE: Always write HTML outside the PHP its the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have not enclosed the PHP along with the HTML tags that you have used. Hence you have to use the code like this.

```
<?php
$pqr = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($pqr))
{
?>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="<?php echo $row[2].$row[3]; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row[2].$row[3]; ?>" width="270"/></a>
<?php
}
?>
```